# Fetching Contacts From People Hub

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am building a Windows Phone 8 application. For that I require to fetch contacts from People Hub App. Is there any way I can keep these contacts even after the application closes?

I have looked into data caching but if the contact has been updated then caching won't work.

Comment: I hope to make the app faster by saving the contacts rather than querying for them every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done.
I've implemented this with the [Group Contacts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacVrH9xpYc) app.

In my solution, I used SQLite to store contacts into various categories based on user preference.

When the app starts up, I initialize my local database using SQLite and pull contacts from there as well as retrieving all the contacts the phone itself.

Example:

```
await ContactsRepository.Instance.Initialize();
var appContacts = await ContactsRepository.Instance.Get();
var phoneContacts = await ContactServices.Instance.LoadContacts(Contacts, SelectedCategory);

MergeContacts(appContacts, phoneContacts);
```

.
.

When ever the app starts up, it needs to create a database if one does not already exist.

Example:

```
public async Task Initialize()
{
    _connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DATABASE_FILE_NAME);

    await EnsureTableExist<ContactReference>(_connection);
}

private async Task EnsureTableExist<T>(SQLiteAsyncConnection connection) where T : new()
{
    bool noTableExists = false;

    try
    {
        var query = await connection.Table<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.Contains("no such table"))
        {
            noTableExists = true;
        }
    }

    if (noTableExists)
    {
        await connection.CreateTableAsync<T>();
    }
}
```

Windows 8.1 uses a ContactManager to retrieve contacts from the People Hub.

Example:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<Contact>> LoadContacts(ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts, Category category)
        {
            contacts.Clear();

            try
            {
                var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
                var result = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();

                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    contacts.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return contacts;
        }
```

Then I manage my contact collection between the phone's contact list and my app's contact list.

Example:

```
private void MergeContacts(ObservableCollection<ContactReference> appContacts, ObservableCollection<Contact> phoneContacts)
{
    foreach (var contact in phoneContacts)
    {
        var contactExists = appContacts.Any(c => c.ContactId == contact.Id);

        if (!contactExists)
        {
            OthersCategory.Contacts.Add(contact);
        }

        Category category = GetCategory(contact);

        if (category == null)
        {
            OthersCategory.Contacts.Add(contact);
        }
    }

    SortContacts(OthersCategory);
}
```

I created an entity class to support my local database operations.

Example:

```
public class ContactReference
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string ContactId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

NOTE:

The emulator that VS2013 provides does not have a list of imaginary contacts.
As a result, I found testing easier by using my personal phone for debugging.